# How can I set files to be downloadable by a browser button that are uploaded to Firebase Storage?

Tags: php, html, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm working on an admin panel where I have an image gallery of photos uploaded by an app (the app was developed by another company and I can't change anything in it).

The app is uploading images to a Firebase Storage account which I have full access to. Additionally, the app stores an image url with a token in a database. Example: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/reeapp-50481.appspot.com/o/testing%2Fduke.jpg?alt=media&token=90ed99bb-28ec-4ebb-a8c6-3764fc5ec4a3

I am able to populate a gallery of the photos in the admin panel, but I'm having trouble making a download button for the image using typical HTML practices with the url above such as

```
<a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/reeapp-50481.appspot.com/o/testing%2Fduke.jpg?alt=media&token=90ed99bb-28ec-4ebb-a8c6-3764fc5ec4a3" download="myfile.jpg">Download</a>
```

or

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = (event) => {
        var blob = xhr.response;
    };
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/reeapp-50481.appspot.com/o/testing%2Fduke.jpg?alt=media&token=90ed99bb-28ec-4ebb-a8c6-3764fc5ec4a3');
    xhr.send();
```

I *WAS* able to use gsutil to set the content-disposition to attachment, which then allows me to force the download for a user, but as far as I can tell, I can't set a bucket to content-disposition=attachment, just a single object. I'll need all future uploads to be downloadable.

Does anybody know how to set this up either on demand before I attempt the download, or to set up the bucket itself to have this setting so that all future objects in it are downloadable?

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT 1**: It seemed like I was making progress, but now I'm a little unsure of what's happening. I found a way to update the meta data of my Google Cloud storage object, so I can now set the contentDisposition to attachment before attempting to start the download. And it looked like it worked for my first image. But then I tried the same thing with another image and it's not working. Sigh.

```
    function forceDownload(imgRefUrl) {
        var storage = firebase.storage();
        var myFile = storage.refFromURL(imgRefUrl);

        myFile.getMetadata().then((data)=>console.log('BEFORE ', data));

        myFile.updateMetadata({ contentDisposition: 'attachment', contentEncoding: 'binary' }).then( (resp) => {
            console.log('AFTER ', resp);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.onload = (event) => {
                var blob = xhr.response;
            };
            xhr.open('GET', imgRefUrl);
            xhr.send();
            myFile.getMetadata().then((data)=>console.log('COMPLETED ', data));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Handle any errors
            console.log("error", error)
        });
    }
```

So I'm confirming that the content-disposition is now attachment before the download attempt, but still no cigar :-/

**EDIT 2**: Okay, this is completely breaking my brain. I've uploaded the same image 5 times. On the first one, my function above named *forceDownload* works and makes the browser download the image instead of redirecting the browser to display the image. But all the other 4 are still redirecting instead of starting a download. They are all the same file.

The only thing I did differently is on the first one, I had commented out the entire XMLHttpRequest, ran the function to set the meta data, then tried the `<a href="..." download="randomname.jpg">Download</a>` method. I am not able to reproduce that with the others after having tried the full forceDownload function.

So, I uploaded a 6th instance of the same image and ran the forceDownload function with the XMLHttpRequest commented out. Then I click on a link with the download attribute set. And it forced the download.

So, here's what I'm thinking is there's some sort of cache being set in the browser if you attempt to download it before setting the metadata. To test this theory out, I tried a completely new browser, but got the same issue that the browser redirected me instead of downloading the image. I'm at a loss of ideas. Maybe it's cached in firebase?